# Balls going away from the origin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose we have $k$ open balls $B_1,\dots,B_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at $0$ (their radii may be different) and $k$ vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Is it true that $\mu\left(\cup_{i=1}^k (B_i+tv_i)\right)$ is an increasing function of $t\ge 0$? 
Here $\mu(\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: exactly, the question is interesting only for $t$ small, when the balls overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Use induction on $k$. For $k = 1$, this is trivial. Suppose, you have $k+1$ balls. Let $S(t)$ be the region covered by first $k$ balls and $B(t)$ be the region covered by the $(k+1)$th ball at time $t$. Then the volume of $S(t)$ is increasing with $t$. Also, $\mu(S(t) \cup B(t)) = \mu(S(t)) + \mu(B(t)) - \mu(S(t) \cap B(t))$. Place yourself at the center of the $(k+1)$th ball and look around. The centers of all other balls are moving along a straight line away from you. Hence $\mu(S(t) \cap B(t))$ is going down.

Comment: thank you, but the very last statement seems not so trivial. Could you add more detail? (Why should the measure of the intersection decrease?)

Comment: Since the intersection $S(t) \cap B(t)$ decreases with time.

Comment: This seems to be false even in the reference frame of the last ball..

Comment: What seems to be false?

Comment: The fact that the intersection decreases (as a set)

Comment: Do you agree that from the center of the last ball all other balls seem to be going away?

Comment: yes, this is clear. But even when k=1 (that is to say, when there are only two balls) the intersection is not decreasing as a set

Comment: The point is that the other balls are moving radially away - Since $t(v_{k+1} - v_i)$ is parallel to $v_{k+1} - v_i$. In that case the overlapping region does decrease.

Comment: To avoid pathological situations like some balls are inside you last ball, you can take the $k+1$th ball to be the smallest ball and let $t_0$ be the first time when no other balls contains the $k+1$th ball. Before $t_0$ you have only $k$ balls. After $t_0$, the overlapping region is going down.

Comment: Why does the overlapping region go down after $t_0$? (and in which sense?) Thank you for your patience.